# Store several places in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a hopefully simple question. I have simplified the code below and it needs to be run on two separate occasions. Is it possible and how do I do? The documents are usually bigger than 200 pages.

```
Sub findAndStore()
Dim pgf As Paragraph
For Each pgf In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If pgf.Range.text = "[table]" & vbCr Then
        'store place in document
    End If
Next
End Sub

Sub addTables()
for each stored place in document do
    Call AddTable("place in document")
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The second part should be run from the bottom up so as not to destroy the saved places in the document.

Comment: I would go with bookmarks (if it is not possible to insert direct at the found position)
like myBo + counter. set a bookmark around the found range.
And then move through the bookmarks checking starting with myBo and insert Table and delete the bookmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Utilize bookmarks to mark the position, and subsequently remove the bookmark after inserting the table.
- Bookmarks are stored within the document, ensuring they are retained even upon reopening the document.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub findAndStore()
    Dim pgf As Paragraph
    Dim iIndex As Long
    For Each pgf In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If pgf.Range.Text = "[table]" & vbCr Then
            ' Insert Bookmark
            With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
                .Add Range:=pgf.Range, Name:="TableBK" & iIndex
                .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
                .ShowHidden = False
            End With
            iIndex = iIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub addTables()
    Dim oBK As Bookmark
    ' Loop through bookmark and insert table
    For Each oBK In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        Call AddTable(oBK.Range)
        oBK.Delete
    Next
End Sub

' Add table next to [table]
Sub AddTable(BKRng As Range)
    Dim tabRng As Range
    Set tabRng = ActiveDocument.Range(BKRng.End, BKRng.End)
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=tabRng, _
         NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2, _
         DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
         AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Red Hare and taller, your suggestion with a long lasting solution is even better.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim col As Collection 'global to store ranges

Sub findAndStore()
    Dim pgf As Paragraph
    Set col = New Collection
    For Each pgf In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If pgf.Range.Text = "[table]" & vbCr Then
            col.Add pgf.Range.Duplicate 'store a copy of `rng`
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub addTables()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In col 'loop through saved ranges
        AddTable rng
    Next rng
End Sub

'dummy sub
Sub AddTable(rng As Range)
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add rng, 2, 5
End Sub
```